# What are the files with .eap extension which Axis Cameras use?

Tags: camera, file-extension

Axis Network Cameras have a control interface which can be accessed by typing out a camera's IP address and pressing enter. There is a tab called applications which lets us upload and install pre built applications to our Axis Camera. Only applications with the extension of .eap can be uploaded, or rather the installer for an application. I'm wondering what are these .eap files and how would I export my project as an .eap file so I could upload it to my Axis Camera.

Comment: Try to rename extension from `eap` to `zip`, usually companies use their own extension to recognize the file as their own, however they put archived program/media inside.Once it is *installed* via web, they unpack it and allow to use. Also should try to "edit" the file as it might contain only XML content.

Comment: Hello, it gives me a file inside which doesn't have an extension and when I open it with an editor, it gives me the same random page the .eap file gave me.

Comment: So it is probably assembly/sth like `exe` file, but for the camera's OS. As developers don't have any API presented on webpage, I don't really think this is clearly open for uploading/modification of own files. Probably the best would be contacting them and ask for more details.

Comment: Found out in the meantime that .eap stands for Embedded Axis Package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EAP files are simple `tar.gz` files. You can see the `tar` command in `doMakeTheTar` function in `eap-create.sh` script. So you can make your own `eap` files using `tar`.